# Why visual studio code call Closure objects that aren't a closure

Tags: javascript, visual-studio-code, closures, vscode-debugger, ecma

During some tries with the debugger in javascript (Node.js), I surprised that VSCode call "Closure" objects that are not an "Abstract Closure" (in terms of https://tc39.es/ecma262/#sec-abstract-closure).
I'm wondering why VSCode debugger shows to me that name.

If I understood correctly from the ecma, that are the lexical scope not the closure itself.

[image]

```
function outer () {
    const a = "some text";

    function middle() {
        const b = "other text"

        return function inner() {
            console.log(a, b)
        }
    }

    const x = middle()
    return x // line where the debugger says "Closure"
}

const c = outer();

c()
```

Comment: They are closure. Technically, `a` should not have scope after or before line 16 but it will, as its is referenced in returning `inner` function. Hence closure

Comment: No closure are invocable objects. Please read the definition by ecma

Comment: ah, you are referring that the "closure" name there means that "middle" and "outer" are closure? and from that scope "import" that variable? if read like that make sense.

Comment: Please post code, error messages, markup, data structures, and other textual information **as text**, not just as a *picture* of text. Why: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/157247

Comment: @allevo, closure essentially means ability of a variable to exists outside its scope. What you are referring is a spec which is independent of language and every language will have their own way to implement. For JS, refer [this](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Closures)

Answer (score 3):

The section you've linked to isn't defining the term "closure" in its general sense, it's defining the **specification** term "Abstract Closure:"

> The *Abstract Closure* specification type is used to refer to algorithm steps together with a collection of values.

That's *a* closure, but not the only kind that can exist, and it's just a mechanism for explaining things in the specification.

VS Code is using the term "[closure](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Closures)," not Abstract Closure. All functions in JavaScript are closures: Whenever a function is created, it gets a link to the [*environment record*](https://tc39.es/ecma262/#sec-environment-records) that the function closed over (the link is called [`[[Environment]]`](https://tc39.es/ecma262/#table-internal-slots-of-ecmascript-function-objects) in the spec). When resolving references to bindings (loosely, "variables") within the function code, that link is used (and its link to its outer environment, etc.) to find the relevant binding.

What VS Code is telling you is that the function `x` refers to closes over the environment for the call to `middle`, which in turn closes over the call to `outer`, which in turn closes over the global environment. (And it's also showing the contents of those environments, which is handy.)

Comment: And here I thought I knew closures and how they work. Thanks for this answer, I never knew about `[[Environment]]`

Comment: If I understood correctly, the "closure" in the debgger is in the sense of: "The scope there are the combination between lexical environments that came from the 'closure' (=function) middle / outer". do I understood correctly?
If yes, why they didn't put "environment" there?

Comment: @allevo - The environment is part of the closure. A closure is the combination of a function and data  ([more](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Closure_(computer_programming))). But I don't have any specific knowledge of why VS Code uses the term there.

Comment: I think this more or less represents what the engine is doing as that's what the view in the debugger is based on. While the spec specifies that all variables are stored in an EnvironmentRecord, engines will rather store variables on the stack. Only when a function leaves it's environment, it creates a heap allocated structure with the variable values (V8 calls it 'Context' as far as I can see) and really creates a (Function, Context) tuple.